# where should I declare the static instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

what is the difference between these singleton implementations:

1. declaring static instance outside the sharedManager functions

   ```
   @implementation MyManager

   static MyManager * manager = nil;

   +(instancetype)sharedManager
   {
       @synchronized(self) {
           if(manager==nil){
               manager = [[MyManager alloc]init];
           }
           return manager;
       }
   }
   ```

   2.

   declaring static instance inside the sharedManager function

   ```
   @implementation MyManager

            +(instancetype)sharedManager
               {
                   static MyManager * manager = nil;
                   @synchronized(self) {
                       if(manager==nil){
                           manager = [[MyManager alloc]init];
                       }
                       return manager;


      }
           }
   @end
   ```

   3. declaring MyManager as extern in the interface

4.

```
+ (instancetype)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *singleton=nil;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        singleton = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return singleton;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make it a static variable inside the accessor method.  This prevents you from accidentally accessing it before it's been properly initialized.

The modern way to initialize a singleton safely is like this:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *singleton;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        singleton = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return singleton;
}
```

`dispatch_once` is significantly faster than `@synchronized` if the once-block has already been performed.

Comment: there is some tutorial initialize singleton with nil, (I edit the question),I think that incorrect because we'll release singleton instance when calling sharedManager function! right ?

Comment: You don't have to worry about initializing `singleton` in the declaration.  If you're using ARC (which you should be), the compiler will initialize it to `nil` be default.  If you're not using ARC, it doesn't matter how it's initialized.

Comment: yes yes that's right but I want to understand why the fourth implementation works fine , because when I call sharedManger at the first time I'will initialize the singleton, and when I call sharedManager at the second time , singleton will be nil. right?

Comment: A static local variable has the same lifetime as a global variable, but is only visible in the function where it's declared.